# What happens when you beat Mu 12 in Arcade mode?

Tags: blazblue-continuum-shift-extend

I’m going through the complete *BlazBlue* series of games. I’m on the second *Continuum Shift Extend* for PC. Under certain conditions, I get to a boss named Mu-12 after the last boss (Hazama). However, I can never beat her. So my question is what happens if I do? I have tried to find something online (like a video) but there is nothing.

On a related note, can I use the following trick to retry the battle?

1. Use a second controller when I’m about to lose to start a PvP battle.
2. Win it.
3. I can now retry the Mu12 battle.

Is this accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Soo... I did it!!!

Yesterday I finally managed to beat Mu-12. I did it using the trick above. You need to have a second player pad (in my case the keyboard) press start (in this case the Tab button) when you are about to loose. In order to trigger the dummy fight. Please remember to ALSO set the number of vs player rounds to 1 in order to make your life a lot easier.

But now to answer my own question: Nothing. Nothing happens. The credits roll exactly as the they would when you loose. The only difference is that you get an achievement. But since I don't care about them, it was pretty anti climatic.

In case you are wondering about a strategy, well this is what I did.

Picked Ragna, in stylish mode. Remember 1 round and difficulty in beginner.

You need to not loose any fights (the only one that is dangerous is hazama himself) and get 1 astral finish. That is it.

When you get to Mu 12 I spammed the forward + special button of the stylish layout. This is his hell's fang and additional attack. If she gets away from you pursuit with the same attack. Once her HP is low enough (you should have gotten 100% heat) finish her off with the astral finish. This is basically gambling. You need to try it enough times until you get lucky. The astral finish has a SUPER short reach for Ragna and the foward C move I just say pushes you away from her, so you can follow up from it. For me, it took about 7 or 8 times. Would have gone a LOT faster had I remembered to set the VS battles to 1 round.

Hope this helps some one.